DRF how to choose serializer for a field based on value of another field
So the problem is I would like to choose the serializer to be used to serialize a particular field based on the value of another field, so for example (pseudocode):
class SerializerA(serializers.Serializer):
   ...
class SerializerB(serializers.Serializer):
   ...
class OverruleSerializer(serialzers.Serializer):
    resolve_type = serializers.CharField()
    sut_name = serializers.CharField()
    overrule_data = SerializerA if resolve_type == "some_type" else SerializerB

Is this possible? I have tried using SerializerMethodField, or overriding to_representation, but no luck

That's what you want to achieve..!
     def get_overrule_data(self, obj):
        resolve_type = obj.get('resolve_type')
        data = obj.get('overrule_data')
        
        if resolve_type == "some_type":
            serializer = SerializerA(data=data)
        else:
            serializer = SerializerB(data=data)

